how can i color several ranges background in google sheet
I have an api to color the background but when I need it to iterate over few ranges the code crash after too many calls.
So I thought on 2 optional solution:

Rearrange the sheet so all the ranges of the same color will become one big range
change the color api to be able to color a few ranges simultaneously.

I am having trouble execute those solutions and be grateful for help.
current API for coloring the background:
    def color(self, sheet_id, red=1.0, green=1.0, blue=1.0, start_row=0, end_row=0):
        try:
            service = build('sheets', 'v4', credentials=self.creds)
            request = {
                "requests": [
                    {
                        "repeatCell": {
                            "range": {
                                "sheetId": sheet_id,
                                "startRowIndex": start_row,
                                "endRowIndex": end_row
                            },
                            "cell": {
                                "userEnteredFormat": {
                                    "backgroundColor": {
                                        "red": red,
                                        "green": green,
                                        "blue": blue
                                    }
                                }
                            },
                            "fields": "userEnteredFormat(backgroundColor)"
                        }

                    }
                ]
            }
            return service.spreadsheets().batchUpdate(spreadsheetId=self.spreadsheet_id, body=request).execute()
        except Exception as err:
            handle_sheets_error("color", "general_error", err=err)


I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, I cannot understand your question. In order to correctly understand your question, can you provide the sample input and output situations you expect? First, I would like to correctly understand your question.

thank you for the reply, I solved it already by adding conditional formatting in the google sheet itself.
